# TypeError: setTimeout is not a function

Tags: node.js, function, asynchronous, settimeout

I'm trying to implement a setTimeout() on my node.js application, but I can't make it work.

I'm first trying with a simple snippet but still, not working. Please see the code snippet bellow:

```
    import setTimeout from 'timers/promises'

    console.log('It will be printed 1-st');

    async function newStyleDelay() {

       await setTimeout(5000);

       console.log('It will be printed 3-rd with delay');
    }

    newStyleDelay();

    console.log('It will be printed 2-nd');


[Terminal][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS1gu.jpg
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the terminal output and not a link.

Comment: Should be `import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises'`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than importing setTimeout you can directly use it. Added sample below.

```
const sleepFunc = async (timeOut = 1000) => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, timeOut);
});

console.log('It will be printed 1-st');

async function newStyleDelay() {
  await sleepFunc(5000);

  console.log('It will be printed 3-rd with delay');
}

newStyleDelay();

console.log('It will be printed 2-nd');
```

Comment: thank you it worked! Another question if you dont mind:

(timeOut = 1000)

What is this doing?

Comment: This is just a default value, if you don't pass any value in sleepFunc then it will take 1000 as default value